# React Native Expo unable to access files above the root

Tags: reactjs, react-native

React Native Expo project is unable to access files above the root, I can't from the src dir go to import some module from  ../../SharedBusinessLogic

I need to do this as the RN is in a project with multiple projects needing to share the same non-framework specific business logic.

ie

repository:

```
/

    /SolidjsProject
    /CloudProject
    /ExpoProject
    /SharedBusinessLogic (no package.json)
```

I get people saying just move the /SharedBusinessLogic into ExpoProject, but that is non-sensical in 2022.

Comment: This is expected behavior. What prevents you from moving the directory into `src`?

Comment: thx @alexanderdavide I am sharing the code across projects and don't want to use a monorepo. I've been fighting this for 7 years, why is RN different to all other projects in this regard, so inflexible. The same code is shared with a RN one, a firebase one and a Solidjs one.

Comment: @Nikos, not sure if you checked this out yet, but there is a potential solution you could check out that is outlined [here](https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/16239) that could work for you. It would likely require that your SharedBusinessLogic folder is an npm project itself. Happy to provide a more detailed answer if necessary.

Comment: as I mentioned, using another npm project is an overkill. It boggles my mind why this metro bundler is so inflexible to modern dev needs.

Comment: @Nikos, OK but... What if `SharedBusinessLogic` uses an npm package, let's say axios, as an example, and in `SolidjsProject` you are using axios v 0.27.x but, `CloudProject` uses axios v 0.22.x instead? What if the two versions have breaking changes? Which version should be used in `SharedBusinessLogic` then? That's why we have a `package.json` file and the related lock file. And that's what @rexessilfie was trying to suggest, I suppose.

Comment: this package will not use npm

Comment: @Nikos, maybe there is a way to achieve this without having the SharedBusinessLogic be its own npm package, though I am not yet aware of such an approach. Maybe opening an issue on Expo or even Metro's GitHub page might yield better solutions. It looks like this is a fundamental limitation with the metro bundler.

Comment: I opened a discussion thx: https://github.com/react-native-community/discussions-and-proposals/issues/483